# UI doesn´t update when recieves parameters from server - JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx

We've been developing a chat, we use javafx for the interface, the problem is when we recieve a message from the server appears this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not on FX application thread; currentThread = Thread-4
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.checkFxUserThread(Toolkit.java:279)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.checkFxUserThread(QuantumToolkit.java:423)
    at javafx.scene.Parent$2.onProposedChange(Parent.java:367)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
    at guichat.Procesos.createBubble(Procesos.java:232)
    at guichat.Procesos.MostrarMensajeAmigo(Procesos.java:204)
    at guichat.Procesos.MensajeRecibido(Procesos.java:192)
    at guichat.Procesos.mensajeria(Procesos.java:177)
    at guichat.HomeController.run(HomeController.java:285)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

We've been looking at posts with the same problem, we know that we can't update a JavaFX element the way we're doing it because it's a different thread.

This is my class Procesos:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package guichat;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import guichat.Modelos.Amigo;
import guichat.Modelos.Usuario;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import  guichat.Modelos.Comunicacion;
import guichat.Modelos.Mensaje;
import guichat.Modelos.MensajeGrupo;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
/**
 *
 * @author usuario
 */
public class Procesos {

   public static String ip;
   public static int puerto;
   public static Socket soquet;
   public static VBox mensajes;
   public static Gson json = new Gson();

   public Procesos()
   {

   }

    public static String getIp() {
        return ip;
    }

    public static void setIp(String ip) {
        Procesos.ip = ip;
    }

    public static int getPuerto() {
        return puerto;
    }

    public static void setPuerto(int puerto) {
        Procesos.puerto = puerto;
    }

   public static void CrearSocket(String ip, int puerto)
   {     
       try {
           soquet= new Socket(ip,puerto);
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Procesos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
       }
   }

   public static double Login(String usuario, String contraseña, String servidor){
        String ip= servidor;
        Usuario user = new Usuario();
        Comunicacion modeloInput = new Comunicacion();
        Comunicacion modeloOutput = new Comunicacion();
        try {
            Procesos.CrearSocket(ip, 4567);
            DataOutputStream dataOutput=new DataOutputStream(Procesos.soquet.getOutputStream());
            user.setUsername(usuario);
            user.setPassword(contraseña);
            modeloOutput.setTipo(Comunicacion.MTypes.RQ_LOGIN);
            modeloOutput.setContenido(user);
            dataOutput.writeUTF(json.toJson(modeloOutput));
            DataInputStream dataInput= new DataInputStream(Procesos.soquet.getInputStream());
            modeloInput= json.fromJson(dataInput.readUTF(), Comunicacion.class);
            if (modeloInput.getTipo()== Comunicacion.MTypes.ACK_LOGIN) {
                System.out.println(modeloInput.getContenido());
                if ((double)modeloInput.getContenido()==210.0) {
                    return (double)modeloInput.getContenido();
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException I) {
            I.getMessage();
            return 0;
        }
       return 0;

    }    

    public static double Register(String nick, String contraseña, String servidor){
        System.out.println("Hola");
        Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
        Comunicacion modeloRespuesta = new Comunicacion();
        Comunicacion modeloPeticion = new Comunicacion();

        try {
            System.out.println("Entre");
            Procesos.CrearSocket(servidor, 4567);
            DataOutputStream peticion = new DataOutputStream(Procesos.soquet.getOutputStream());
            usuario.setUsername(nick);
            usuario.setPassword(contraseña);
            modeloPeticion.setTipo(Comunicacion.MTypes.RQ_REG);
            modeloPeticion.setContenido(usuario);
            peticion.writeUTF(json.toJson(modeloPeticion));

            DataInputStream  respuesta = new DataInputStream(Procesos.soquet.getInputStream());
            modeloRespuesta= json.fromJson(respuesta.readUTF(), Comunicacion.class);

            if (modeloRespuesta.getTipo()== Comunicacion.MTypes.ACK) {
                System.out.println(modeloRespuesta.getContenido());
                if ((double)modeloRespuesta.getContenido()==220.0) {
                    return (double)modeloRespuesta.getContenido();
                }
            }

        } catch (IOException I) {
            I.getMessage();
            return 0;
        }
       return 0;
    }

    public static void EnviarMensajes(String txtMessage)
    {

        DataOutputStream EnviarCadena = null;
        Usuario origen = new Usuario();
        origen.setId(1);
        System.out.println("Enviando mensaje");
        try {

            Comunicacion modeloOutput = new Comunicacion();
            System.out.println(txtMessage);
            Mensaje mensaje_enviar= new Mensaje();
            Usuario usuario_destino = new Usuario();
            usuario_destino.setId(2);
            mensaje_enviar.setDestino(usuario_destino);
            mensaje_enviar.setOrigen(origen);
            mensaje_enviar.setContenido(txtMessage);
            modeloOutput.setTipo(Comunicacion.MTypes.RQ_MENSAJE);
            modeloOutput.setContenido(mensaje_enviar);
            EnviarCadena = new DataOutputStream(soquet.getOutputStream());
            EnviarCadena.writeUTF(json.toJson(modeloOutput));

            DataInputStream RecibirConfirmacion= new DataInputStream(soquet.getInputStream());
            RecibirConfirmacion.readUTF();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Procesos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } 

    }

    public static void RecibirPeticiones()
    {
         Gson jayson= new Gson();
        Comunicacion modelo = new Comunicacion();
        try {
            DataInputStream dataInput= new DataInputStream(soquet.getInputStream());
            modelo= jayson.fromJson(dataInput.readUTF(), Comunicacion.class);
            mensajeria(modelo);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage();
}
    }
    public static void mensajeria(Comunicacion modelo)
    {

          Gson json= new Gson(); 
          String data = json.toJson(modelo.getContenido());
        switch(modelo.getTipo())
            {
                case SEND_MENSAJE:
                    MensajeRecibido(json.fromJson(data, Mensaje.class));
                    break;
                case SEND_GRUPO:
                    MensajeGrupoRecibido(json.fromJson(data, MensajeGrupo.class));
                    break;
                case SEND_CONECTADOS:

                    break;
                case SEND_DESCONECTADOS:

                    break;
            }
}
    public static void MensajeRecibido(Mensaje mensaje)
    {
        MostrarMensajeAmigo(mensaje);
    }
    public static void MensajeGrupoRecibido(MensajeGrupo mensaje_grupo)
    {

    }
    public static void Lista_Conectados(Amigo AmigosConectados)
    {

    }

    private static void MostrarMensajeAmigo(Mensaje mensaje) {
        Interfaz.createBubble(mensajes, Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE, mensaje.getContenido(), null);
    }


}
```

And this is my class HomeController:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package guichat;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import guichat.Components.CButton;
import guichat.Modelos.Comunicacion;
import guichat.Modelos.Mensaje;
import guichat.Modelos.MensajeGrupo;
import guichat.Modelos.Amigo;
import guichat.Modelos.Grupo;
import guichat.Modelos.Usuario;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import guichat.Procesos;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 * FXML Controller class
 *
 * @author Wero
 */
public class HomeController implements Initializable,Runnable {
    String ip;
    // Controles implementados en Interfaz
    @FXML private Button closeWindowBtn, minimizeWindowBtn, outBtn, groupBtn, deleteBtn, editBtn;
    @FXML private TextArea txtMessage;
    @FXML private VBox messagesVBox, groupsVBox, friendsVBox;
    @FXML private TextField txtCurrentContact;

    // Variables de control internas
    private Boolean type = false;
    private String username;
    private Boolean flagEdit = false;
    private Boolean typeEdit = true;
    private String contact;
    private String[] users = {
        "Arturo Carrillo",
        "Kevin Alan",
        "Vanya Martínez",
        "Jimena Zaragoza",
        "Juan Antonio",
        "Emiliano Moreno",
        "Eduardo Fuentes"
    };

    /**
     * Método para hacer pruebas en la pantalla
     */
    public void insertContent(){
        Boolean flag = false;
        for(String user : users){
            Interfaz.createBubble(messagesVBox, flag, type, user, null);
            if(flag) flag = false;
            else flag = true;
        }
        int contador = 0;
        for(String user : users){
            createFriend(user, contador);
            contador++;
        }
        for(String user : users){
            createGroup(user, contador);
            contador++;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Método para crear el boton del grupo
     * @param name String Nombre del grupo
     * @param id int Identificador en la base de datos del grupo
     */
    public void createGroup(String name, int id){
        CButton group = new CButton(name);
        group.setIdElement(id);
        group.setNameElement(name);
        group.getStyleClass().add("chat-btn");
        group.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if(event.getSource() == group){
                    messagesVBox.getChildren().clear();
                    System.out.println("Id del Grupo: " + group.getIdElement());
                    txtCurrentContact.setText(group.getNameElement());
                    contact = group.getNameElement();
                    type = true;
                    typeEdit = true;
                    editBtn.setDisable(false);
                    deleteBtn.setDisable(false);
                }
            }
        });
        groupsVBox.getChildren().add(group);
    }

    /**
     * Método para crear el boton del amigo
     * @param name String Nombre o apodo del amigo
     * @param id int Identificador en la base de datos del amigo
     */
    public void createFriend(String name, int id){
        CButton user = new CButton(name);
        user.setIdElement(id);
        user.setNameElement(name);
        user.getStyleClass().add("chat-btn");
        user.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
                if(event.getSource() == user){
                    messagesVBox.getChildren().clear();
                    System.out.println("Id del usuario: " + user.getIdElement());
                    txtCurrentContact.setText(user.getNameElement());
                    type = false;
                    contact = user.getNameElement();
                    editBtn.setDisable(false);
                    deleteBtn.setDisable(false);
                    typeEdit = false;
                }
            }
        });
        friendsVBox.getChildren().add(user);
    }

    /**
     * Editar información de contacto
     * @param e 
     */
    @FXML
    public void editContact(ActionEvent e){
        if(!flagEdit){
            editBtn.setText("Aceptar");
            txtCurrentContact.setDisable(false);
            flagEdit = true;
            txtCurrentContact.requestFocus();
        }else{
            if(!txtCurrentContact.getText().equals(contact)){
                System.out.println("Nuevo nombre del elemento: " + txtCurrentContact.getText());
                contact = txtCurrentContact.getText();
            }
            editBtn.setText("Editar");
            txtCurrentContact.setDisable(true);
            flagEdit = false;
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void deleteContact(ActionEvent e){
        System.out.println("Falta implementar funcionalidad del botón de eliminar");
    }

    /**
     * Método para poder cerrar la pestaña
     * @param e ?
     */
    @FXML
    public void handleCloseWindow(ActionEvent e){
        Stage stage = (Stage) closeWindowBtn.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    /**
     * Método para minimizar la pestaña
     * @param e 
     */
    @FXML
    public void handleMinimizeWindow(ActionEvent e){
        Stage stage = (Stage) minimizeWindowBtn.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.setIconified(true);
    }

    /**
     * Método para pasar el nombre de usuario de una vista a otra
     * @param username String Nombre de Usuario
     */
    public void setUsername(String username){
        this.username = username;
        System.out.println(this.username);
    }
    public void setip(String ip){
        this.ip = ip;
        System.out.println(this.ip);
    }


    /**
     * Método para cerrar sesión del Usuario
     * @param e 
     */
    @FXML
    public void signOut(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
            Stage stage = (Stage) outBtn.getScene().getWindow();
            Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
            stage.setScene(scene);
        }catch (IOException io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Método pare redirigir a la pestaña de Creación de Grupos
     * @param e 
     */
    @FXML
    public void goToCreateGroup(ActionEvent e){
        try {
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("Groups.fxml"));
            Stage stage = (Stage) groupBtn.getScene().getWindow();
            Scene scene = new Scene(loader.load());
            stage.setScene(scene);
            GroupsController group = loader.getController();
            group.setUsername(this.username);
        }catch (IOException io){
            io.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void sendMessage(ActionEvent e){
        Interfaz.createBubble(messagesVBox, Boolean.FALSE, type, txtMessage.getText(), "werofuentes");
        Procesos.EnviarMensajes(txtMessage.getText());
        txtMessage.setText("");
    }

    /**
     * Método para inicializar los componentes de la Interfaz
     * @param url ?
     * @param rb ?
     */
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        // TODO
        insertContent();
        Procesos.mensajes = messagesVBox;
        Thread hilo = new Thread(this);
        hilo.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Corriendo");

        try {

            ServerSocket response = new ServerSocket(7654);

            System.out.println("Entre al try");

            while(true) {

                System.out.println("Entre al while");

                Gson json = new Gson();

                Socket peticion = response.accept();

                DataInputStream datos = new DataInputStream(peticion.getInputStream());

                String da = datos.readUTF();

                Comunicacion modelo = json.fromJson(da, Comunicacion.class);

                Procesos.mensajeria(modelo);

                peticion.close();

                response.close();

            }

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(HomeController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

}
```

We know that we should use Task or Platform.runLater but we don't undestand how they work.

Comment: Instead of dumping your entire source try and create a [mcve], then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Have a look at these crud apps [MessagingApp1](https://github.com/sedj601/MessagingApp1) and [MessagingApp2](https://github.com/sedj601/-MessagingApp2). You can see if you can get some ideas from them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Platform.runLater when you have some operation (not a complicated one though) that you want to update your UI with from non-UI thread. It will queue your task and handle it in UI thread as soon as possible (but it is never said when exactly).

I can't really run your code, so what you need to do is wrap your UI changing code (that is fired when server data comes into your client) in Platform.runLater like below:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> Interfaz.createBubble(mensajes, Boolean.TRUE, Boolean.FALSE, mensaje.getContenido(), null));
```

More on runLater [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/application/Platform.html#runLater-java.lang.Runnable-)